# navbar toggle button shifts right and top 30px on click

Tags: bootstrap-4

i have a bootstrap 4 navbar on my webpage and it has a toggle button which is on right side. But when i click on it, it shifts right and top by 30px and then when it collapses, it shifts back. This looks weird. I want my toggle button to appear on right and should not move on click.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1475fd3000.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler m-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown float-right">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Product
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Action</a></li>                        
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Knowledge Base</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Partners</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
          </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            More
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle language" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            EN
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AR</a></li>            
          </ul>
        </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn text-white" href="#">Get Started</a>
          </li>  
          
          
        
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```